# Permanently disabling wifi

Tags: wi-fi

Nexus 5, rooted running paranoid android.

So my wifi stopped working about 4 months ago, I did ever reset under the sun. Jumped between ROMs all to no avail. Seems hardware related. That's fine I have unlimited data. The problem is that even with no functioning wifi it's trying it's hardest to find a network. Just scanning over and over, never connecting. Problem is I can't turn it off. I click the switch and nothing happens, it just stays on draining my already meager battery.

Comment: Does `adb shell su -c svc wifi disable` do anything?

Comment: delete or rename your wifi module in `/system/lib/modules` .